# How do you measure the size of a cgi.FieldStorage instance?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wsgi

When a file is uploaded, the standard way of representing it is `cgi.FieldStorage` (at least Pyramid does it that way). However, if I want to know the length in an efficient way, how do I get it? For example:

```
uploaded = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

If this variable now came from a request, how to determine the file's size?

Answer (score 9):

The least efficient way would be this:

```
size = len(uploaded.value)
```

Better:

```
uploaded.file.seek(0, 2)
size = uploaded.file.tell()
uploaded.file.seek(0)
```

Best:

```
import os
size = os.fstat(uploaded.file.fileno()).st_size
```

The last option is the preferred way to measure a file's in C and Python only proxies this through. It returns [a structure](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) that can tell you all sorts of stuff, even the size of a file.